# How to implement my query in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I used this query to make a table NewAddData

```
select (
    FirstName +' '+
    coalesce(MiddleInitial + '''', '') +
    ' ' +
    Lastname
) as Name
into NewAddData
from c_client c;
```

I'm getting the following output if I do

```
Select * from NewAddData
```

[image]

I want to get name which has apostrophe present in it.
The Select Statement is working as

```
Select Name from AddData where Name like '%Paige%' and Name like '%''%'
```

And I'm getting the output as `Paige A'Harrell`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName Varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select Name from AddData where Name like '%@ClientName%' and Name like '%''%'
END
GO
```

I'm trying to do this in Stored Procedure, but it is not working.
I want to pass any part of the name as parameter and if it has apostrophe, I want to get that name as output.
If that name doesn't have apostrophe, it should show that name is not present.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

write '%'+@ClientName+'%' inplace '%@ClientName%'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName Varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select Name from AddData where Name like '%'+@ClientName+'%' and Name like '%''%'
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName Varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
           SELECT NAME FROM ADDDATA WHERE  NAME IN
       (
        SELECT TOKEN
        FROM UDF_SPLITSTRING(@CLIENTNAME, ',')
        )
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you further modify the Stored Procedure to accept more than one input?

Comment: @ShekhAdnan if you want add extra inputs use in where clause  like how i used

Comment: EXEC GetName 'Adnan,Rahul'
I want to pass two names like this.

Comment: @ShekhAdnan use split_string function comma seperated values will be converted into seperate rows then use the following code

Comment: @ShekhAdnan check the answer

Comment: How can I do it by using @sql variable and using EXEC in stored procedure.

Comment: I don't want to use EXEC sp_executesql

Comment: @ShekhAdnan now who asked to run with sp_executesql 
now directly use exec ClientName   'Adnan,Rahul'  it will work if you use 2016 version

Comment: brother can you please check the new question I just posted?

Comment: please add data instead of images

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490813/can-someone-convert-the-code-so-that-it-uses-exec-sql-and-not-exec-sp-executesq?noredirect=1#comment89950598_51490813

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if exists(select [name] from AddData where [name] LIKE concat('%', @ClientName, '%') and [name] like '%''%')
        begin
            select @ClientName
        end
    else
        begin 
            select @ClientName + ' is not found'
        end
END
```