# Can someone convert the code so that it uses EXEC @sql and not EXEC sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server

This is my Stored Procedure which I would like to convert:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName nVarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @name = '%'+@ClientName+'%'
    SET @sql=
    'SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like @name'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@name NVARCHAR(MAX)',@name=@name
END
GO
```

Comment: What is your goal for such converting?

Comment: My master asked to do like this. I have tried but couldn't get the desired output.

Comment: `Name like @name'` becomes `Name like '''+@name+''''`. Because you have quotes inside a string, you need to double them up to escape them, so the processor doesn't think the string has ended

Comment: do a `PRINT @sql` to examine the dynamic query. You should be able to spot any mistake there

Comment: maybe you should also refer to https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/

Comment: I tried with that code and used Print @sql
The output is:-
SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like Name like '%Elijah%'

Comment: So what's the problem now? Other than the fact it repeats 'Name like' twice...

Comment: If I EXEC @sql, the output is:-
Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like Name like '%Elijah%''.

Comment: I corrected the name like, still the same error

Comment: You need to wrap it in brackets: `Exec(@sql)`

Comment: Got it bro. Thanks a ton. I'm a newbie in this thing. Thanks.

Comment: One more question:-
If I try to pass a name with apostrophe, it is showing error.
for ex- the name is Oscar I'Baltierra Mora and I'm passing it like EXEC FindName 'Oscar I''Baltierra Mora'
It is showing this error:- 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near 'Baltierra'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 20

Comment: Use Print to work out why the syntax might not be correct. Update your question so other people can help you without going through all these comments.

Comment: What can i correct in this-
SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like '%Oscar I'Baltierra Mora%'

Comment: It's not clear why this is using `EXEC` **at all**, but someone asking you to take code that correctly *maintains* separation between code and data using parameterization and instead forcing parameterization via string concatenation (which you'll be forced to do by removing `sp_executesql`) clearly *doesn't know what they're talking about*.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the action is not clear, but to replace

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName nVarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN   
    EXEC (N'SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like ''%' + @ClientName + '%''')
END
GO
```

Comment: Sure the syntax is correct? I'm pretty sure that `CREATE OR ALTER` does not work in SQL Server...

Comment: Hehe yes, I know CREATE OR REPLACE from Oracle SQL - used to work with it for almost 15 years before switching to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If this is, literally, the entire procedure, then it should just be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetName @ClientName nVarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    Name 
    from AddData 
    where Name like '%' + @ClientName + '%'
END
GO
```

With no need for dynamic SQL at all. On the other hand, if this is the *basis* for a more complex "search" procedure where more parameters than just `@ClientName` will be supplied, you probably ought to read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). In which you still, more than likely, shouldn't be using dynamic SQL (but the article does a fine job of describing when you *might*).

Even there, you'll note that the code samples *do* use `sp_executesql` to maintain appropriate parameterization.